# MongoDB bind_ip error: bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, meteor

I want to configure mongodb to allow remote connections from an external ip address like `66.31.123.123`.

Setting `0.0.0.0` to `bind_ip` works, but I want to be more restrictive and only allow certain ip addresses to connect. I appended `66.31.123.123` to the `bind_ip` list but mongodb throws an error below:

**mongodb.conf**

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,66.31.123.123
port = 27017

auth = true
```

**mongodb logs**

```
Mon Dec  9 03:25:59 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket: 66.31.123.123:27017
```

**Question:** Why does adding an external ip not work? If `auth=true` is used, does that make it safe enough to use `0.0.0.0` as the `bind_ip`? The mongodb will be locally accessed from a Meteor.js app.

Comment: `bind_ip` tells mongod (or mongos) which network interface address to bind to, it will not filter the ip of any incoming connection.

Answer (score 21):

As guido said, the bind_ip is for the mongo server's own IP address.

Auth is a good idea but only relying on auth opens you up to a brute force attack.

You could  `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` and use a firewall to block all incoming connections to port 27017, unless coming from 66.31.123.123.

Another concern is proximity of your meteor server to your mongo server — is it on private networking or across public network. If across public, you should either [recompile mongodb to support SSL](http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-linux/), or you should [tunnel your mongodb connection through SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983795/how-do-i-establish-a-bidirectional-ssh-tunnel).

If you do decide to tunnel, bind_ip to 127.0.0.1 and leave out incoming 27017.