# Get site A to connect to site B's mongo database

Tags: mongodb

I have two websites. **I can connect each site to their own databases** via localhost but I can't get site A to connect to site B's database without getting the famous 'ECONNREFUSED' message.

the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) say edit the mongod.conf `bind_ip` and 'To bind to multiple IP addresses, enter a list of comma separated values.' or you can comment it out to allow all ips...

then `service mongod restart`

I've tried the comma separated list and I've tested commenting it out but the sites refuse each other

lets say site A's ip is 777.777.777.77 and site B's ip is 88.888.88.88

site B's mongo.conf:

```
port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,777.777.777.77
```

and/or this way...

```
port: 27017
#bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Site A tries to connect to site B with:

```
'mongodb://88.888.88.88:27017/db'
```

> Additional info:
>
> I have tested a websocket connecting the two sites together working well so I'm puzzled by mongo saying no.
>
> I'm also using node.js with the native mongo module.
>
> I have no auth or user yet

Enabled port 27017 `TCP_IN` and in `TCP_OUT` in the firewall IPv4 Port Settings for site B but site A is still refused.

I looked in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` and saw:

```
 2016-04-10T16:09:16.250-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket: 777.777.777.77:27017
```

which makes this question look like it's related to this: [MongoDB bind_ip error: bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466250/mongodb-bind-ip-error-bind-failed-errno99-cannot-assign-requested-address-fo)

so I tried switching the bind_ip to

```
127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0
```

but it still refuses

http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

^ the above article says

> Common Mistake
>   Don’t put the Application Server IP in bind_ip option. This bind_ip option tells MongoDB to accept connections from which local network interfaces, not which “remote IP address”.

So I tried switching the bind_ip to

```
127.0.0.1,88.888.88.88
```

but it still refuses (I'm pretty sure this way is correct which may mean something is wrong with my firewall!? I am not an engineer so I will have an engineer look at it tomorrow and hopefully solve the problem and post the result as an answer)

Comment: I am not sure what the network topology is in your case, but if the websites are on different networks you might be having problems with: 1) Firewall - firewall is not allowing connections on 27017 port from anyone outside of the intranet. 2) If firewall is not blocking port 27017 for you, you might need to know what is the public ip address that is being used by 'another' website. So you can copy it to the list of bindip property.

Comment: I think one server is in france... the other I am not sure

Comment: just enabled port 27017 TCP_IN and in TCP_OUT in the firwall IPv4 Port Settings for site B but site A is still refused

Comment: If site_b is a linux machine you will need to configure its firewall settings, also if it is under another external firewall - that thing will need to pass the port 27017 via NAT to the internal mongo server. You can see online tools to check for open ports based on an IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works when surrounded by square brackets

```
bindIp: [127.0.0.1,777.777.777.77]
```